# CRUD operations using mongoose and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am creating an express app using mongoose with the intention of connecting this to React for the frontend.

I have listed some CRUD operations for a **customer controller** below but there are a few things I do not like about this approach.

1. When using `Customer.findById` with a valid ObjectID that is not found, it returns `null` with a 200 response code.  I want this to return 404 if no customer was found.  I realise I could change the `catch` response to a 404, but I want to have some generic error handling incase the server goes down during the request or an invalid ObjectId was provided, which brings me to my next item.
2. If I provide an invalid ObjectId I want to provide some meaningful message, is 500 the right response code?
3. Error handling: Am I returning errors the correct way? currently errors return a string with the error message. Should I return JSON instead? e.g. `res.status(500).json({error: error.message)`.  I am planning on connecting this to react (which I am still learning) and I assume the UI will need to display these messages to the user?
4. `findById` is repeated in `getCustomerById`, `updateCustomer`, and `deleteCustomer`.  I feel this is bad practice and there must be a more streamlined approach?
5. I want to have one function that validates if the ObjectId is valid. I am aware that I can do this is the `routes` using `router.params` but I'm not sure if checking for a valid id should be in the `routes` file as it seems like something the `controller` should be handling? See routes example below from another project I did.

What are the best practices and suggested ways to improve my code, based on the above?
I have read the documentation from mongoose, mozilla, and stackoverflow Q&A but they don't seem to address these issues (at least I could not find it).

I am really after some guidance or validation that what I am doing is correct or wrong.

**customer.controller.js**

```
const Customer = require("../models/customer.model");

exports.getCustomers = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const customers = await Customer.find();
    res.status(200).json(customers);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send(error.message);
  }
};

exports.getCustomerById = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const customer = await Customer.findById(req.params.id);
    res.status(200).json(customer);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send(error.message);
  }
};

exports.addCustomer = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const customer = new Customer(req.body);
    await customer.save().then(res.status(201).json(customer));
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send(error.message);
  }
};

exports.updateCustomer = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const customer = await Customer.findById(req.params.id);
    Object.assign(customer, req.body);
    customer.save();
    res.status(200).json(customer);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send(error.message);
  }
};

exports.deleteCustomer = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const customer = await Customer.findById(req.params.id);
    await customer.remove();
    res.status(200).json(customer);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send(error.message);
  }
};
```

**Router.params example**
This is a routes file (not related to my current app) and is provided as an example of how I have used `router.params` in the past.

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Artist = require("../models/Artist");
const loginRequired = require("../middleware/loginRequired");

const {
  getArtists,
  addArtist,
  getArtistById,
  updateArtist,
  deleteArtist,
} = require("../controllers/artistController");

router
  .route("/")
  .get(loginRequired, getArtists) // Get all artists
  .post(loginRequired, addArtist); // Create a new artist

router
  .route("/:id")
  .get(loginRequired, getArtistById) // Get an artist by their id
  .put(loginRequired, updateArtist) // Update an artist by their id
  .delete(loginRequired, deleteArtist); // Delete an artist by their id

router.param("id", async (req, res, next, id) => {
  // Check if the id is a valid Object Id
  if (mongoose.isValidObjectId(id)) {
    // Check to see if artist with valid id exists
    const artist = await Artist.findOne({ _id: id });
    if (!artist) res.status(400).json({ errors: "Artist not found" });

    res.locals.artist = artist;
    res.locals.artistId = id;

    next();
  } else {
    res.status(400).json({ errors: "not a valid object Id" });
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: You are getting a `ObjectId`'s string value - check that the value is a valid using the `ObjectId.isValid(id)` method of native NodeJS driver (or something similar in Mongoose). If not valid, send a `res.status(404).send({ message: "the provided id is not valid" })` (a response status code of `500` is _not correct_ in this case; it is for unrecoverable server side errors). If it is a valid id, you can perform the database operation using it; for example read a document with that id. If you are expecting an existing document and the document is not found send the same `404` response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i personly like to make error handeling more global so i would write something like

```
constPrettyError = require('pretty-error')
const pe = new PrettyError()

const errorHandler = (err, req, res, next) => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') {
        console.log(pe.render(err))
    }
    return res
        .status(err.status || 500)
        .json({ error: { message: err.message || 'oops something went wrong' } })
}

module.exports = errorHandler
```

as a handler

the in your index / server file

```
app.use(errorHandler)
```

then in your handlers just

```
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
```

as an example

```
 if (!artist) next({ message: "Artist not found" ,status:404 });
```

also, note that you can customize this error handler to switch case (or object) a custom error per status as well if you want

```
const errorHandler = (err, req, res, next) => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') {
        console.log(pe.render(err))
    }
    const messagePerStatus = {
        404: 'not found',
        401: 'no authorization'
    }
    const message = messagePerStatus[err.status]
    return res
        .status(err.status || 500)
        .json({
            error: { message: message || err.message || 'oops something went wrong' }
        })
}
```

then just

```
 if (!artist) next({status:404 });
```

Comment: Just an hint: the error handler in express should be the last middleware loaded in index/server file.

Answer (score 0):

I also agree with answer by Asaf Strilitz but still need to show what i do in my projects

Create a custom error class

AppError.js

```
class AppError extends Error {
  constructor(statusCode, message) {
    super();
    // super(message);
    this.statusCode = statusCode || 500 ;
    this.message = message || "Error Something went wrong";
  }
}

module.exports = AppError;
```

Create an error handling middleware

errors.js

```
const AppError = require("../helpers/appError");

const errors = (err, req, res, next) => {
    // console.log(err);
  
    let error = { ...err };

    error.statusCode = error.statusCode;
    error.message = error.message;

    res.status(error.statusCode).json({
      statusCode: err.statusCode,
      message: err.message,
    });
  };
  
  exports.errors = errors;
```

Create a middleware to validate object id

validateObjectId.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const AppError = require("appError");

module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
  const { _id } = req.params;
  if (_id && !mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(_id)) {
    throw new AppError(422, "Invalid ID field in params");
  }
  next();
};
```

In your app.js

```
const { errors } = require("errors");


// At the end of all middlewares

// Error Handler Middleware
app.use(errors);
```

In your routes file

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Artist = require("../models/Artist");
const loginRequired = require("../middleware/loginRequired");
const validateId = require("validateObjectId");

const {
  getArtists,
  addArtist,
  getArtistById,
  updateArtist,
  deleteArtist,
} = require("../controllers/artistController");

// Your routes
router
  .route("/:id")
  .get(validateId, loginRequired, getArtistById) // Get an artist by their id
  .put(validateId, loginRequired, updateArtist) // Update an artist by their id
  .delete(validateId, loginRequired, deleteArtist); // Delete an artist by their id


module.exports = router;
```

Now regarding findById method being repeated i dont see anything bad in that as  it is specific to database call still you can introduce a staic method on model itself or create a single method on cntroller but still need to check if it returns the found object or not and handle the error on that.